# Maven enable site documentation generation as zip

Tags: maven, documentation-generation

Hey I am trying to generate a Maven project's site documentation as a zip file. I have come across maven assembly plugin but it seems like it is for the entire project, is there a way to let it know only to generate the site as zip? The solution has to be a maven plugin as it needs to be automated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `site:jar`

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/jar-mojo.html

which was designed to bundle the site into one artifact.

Comment: There are no java classes associated with the site. It's entirely static; htmls/css/xml.

Comment: I do not understand how your comment relates to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Assembly Plugin seems the best way to go, you just need to use a proper assembly file to only create a zip using your site. You can specify which files to include using the assembly `<fileSet><directory>...</directory></fileSet>`. Your assembly file can look like:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
    <id>site-zip</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}</directory> <!-- Site output directory -->
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/zipped-site</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```